# Solving $2\sin x\cos x = \sin x$. What did I do wrong?

Tags: trigonometry

The question is to solve the equation
$$2\sin x\cos x = \sin x$$
for $0\leq x \leq 2\pi$.

This is the way in which the math is done in my book : -

[image: 1st way]

This is the way I did the math : -

[image: This is the math]

Now why is my method incorrect?

My exam is the day after tomorrow, that's why I couldn't code the math in mathjax. Please understand my situation.

Comment: And it's because your exam is the day after tomorrow that you've put both of your pictures sideways?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos sorry for that man, my bad

Comment: A general tip: you can always substitute proposed solutions into the first equation and check if they're correct or not. That technique can go a long way when in doubt. As a matter of fact, this should actually be always done in general, but it just happens that for some particular types of equations like linear we know that each step in solving is reversible, so we don't need to check. Squaring is not reversible, for example, because it loses track of the signs.

Comment: @Ennar thank you

Comment: Ask your teacher to switch to another book asap! Show him/her this in order to convince.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution is correct.

By squaring both sides of the equation, the author(s) introduced extraneous solutions, which they failed to check.  Also, the author(s) correctly found the solution $x = 2\pi$, then forgot to list it at the end.

Answer (score 1):

**Shortly:**

$\sin x=0$ is an obvious solution, corresponding to $x=0,\pi,2\pi$. And if $\sin x\ne0$ then $\cos x=\frac12$ so that $x=\frac\pi3$ or $x=\frac{5\pi}3.$

Comment: The author's solution is clumsy and error prone.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct . Furthermore,  the $2\pi/3$ is not a solution as the author writes.  One more point,  after squaring the "iff" case is not valid any more and the author should in the end check if the "solutions" are still valid.